# Getting exit code of a terminated process

Tags: windbg

I'm debugging a process in WinDbg, and the process exited:

```
0:009> g
(bunch of regs...)
ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0xc:
770ad43c c20800          ret     8
0:009> g
       ^ No runnable debuggees error in 'g'
```

At this point, how do I get the process' exit code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could find it as the second argument of [ZwTerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567115%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). [NtTerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557699%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is just the kernel version of it, right?

```
0:000> kb
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
003ff414 7774d5ac ffffffff 1234abcd 00000000 ntdll!ZwTerminateProcess+0x12
003ff430 759c79ec 00000000 77e8f3b0 ffffffff ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess+0x85
...
```

Or the fourth parameter of RtlExitUserProcess

```
0:000> kn
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 003ff414 7774d5ac ntdll!ZwTerminateProcess+0x12
01 003ff430 759c79ec ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess+0x85
...

0:000> .frame 01
01 003ff430 759c79ec ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess+0x85

0:000> dd esp L4
003ff414  7771fcc2 7774d5ac ffffffff 1234abcd
```

Comment: I think ZwTerminateProcess=Kernel, NtTerminateProcess=User. Anyways, works great, thanks!

Comment: In usermode, both Nt* and Zw* are the same function (note the same address for both symbol names): 0:048> `x ntdll!*terminateprocess`
774bbeb0          ntdll!NtTerminateProcess (<no parameter info>)
774bbeb0          ntdll!ZwTerminateProcess (<no parameter info>